# Why is not working bootstrap 4 in .net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I upgrated from bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 4 in NuGet. Everything is fine, B4 is installed properly. But my issue is still in use is bootstrap 3! Bootstrap 4 classes are not working at all. For example:

I can use 
**col-md-6**

but I cannot use **col** class

Comment: Could you show how you import the style sheets?

Comment: I didn't import a thing. I thought I can use those default boundle scripts. @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

Comment: Okay I fixed this problem by adding this

 `<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

So is not enought just `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` or `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")`

Comment: rendering bundles works fine... you just have to include the stylesheets in the style bundle and the scripts in the script bundle. See `BundleConfig.cs`. It sounds like your bundles are still referencing bootstrap 3. After reading your comment, I'm guessing youre now including both bootstrap 3 and bootstrap 4 on your pages which is not something you should be doing. Hard to tell for sure without you posting any code though

Comment: I unistalled Bootstrap 3 then I installed Bootstrap 4. So how can my boundles reference boostrap 3 if there is no bootstrap 3. Thats weird